# Hooking into "Sublime Text has finished loading" event

Tags: sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there an API call to determine if Sublime Text has finished loading, including reopening all files that were open before Sublime was closed last? Maybe there is something similar to `plugin_loaded()`, which gets called after the plugin has finished loading?

If this is not possible, are the files that were open last listed somewhere?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am creating a plugin that, when a file gets opened, opens files that are associated with that file automatically. All of that works fine, but when I start sublime text, I end up with some files opening twice, since I am hooking into the file open event, which seems to get triggered before all files are restored.

Comment: @DudeOnRock I am not sure if there is such API. However, you can get all stored buffers in file `Sublime Text 2\Settings\Session.sublime_session`. So you can compare it with current opened files to see if Sublime Text has restored all stored buffers or not. Or you can just check if a file will be restored, don't open it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is such API. However, you can get all stored buffers in file `Sublime Text 2\Settings\Session.sublime_session` (search "buffers" in it).